# Android share app dialog box display error

Tags: android

im having problem implementing the menu to share my app. When ever i open my activity that has the icon share_button, the dialog box "share via" is displayed immediately. I reckon i have problem with this line of code "startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(), "Share..."));"

here is my code

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);
    // Create the share Intent
    String playStoreLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
        getPackageName();
    String yourShareText = "Install this app " + playStoreLink;
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();
    // Set the share Intent
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(), "Share via"));
    return true;
}
```

menu item

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you code like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainpage, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null);

    return true;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_share:


    String playStoreLink = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +
    getPackageName();
    String yourShareText = "Install this app " + playStoreLink;
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setType("text/plain").setText(yourShareText).getIntent();
    // Set the share Intent
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(), "Share via"));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

- `onCreateOptionsMenu` will call when your activity will call.
- You need to start the share intent when `Share button` pressed`
- So call share Intent in `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: thanks Mohsin, i got an error on this line "startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(), "Share via"));" error: the method shareIntent is undefined.

Comment: remove `()` at the end. Make like this `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));`

Comment: the problem now is the share button on the menu is no longer clickable  when i removed this ()

Answer (score 0):

You have to move this line of code `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent(), "Share via"));` out into a button click handler or menu select handler.

The function `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will be called to setup the menu and that will happen when your `Activity` starts up.